# automated fast svg to raster-image (e.g. png) conversion

Tags: shell, svg

I'm looking for a tool to convert an svg to a raster-image (png for instance) from a shell script (bash).

Currently I use `inkscape --export-png=image.png --export-area-drawing image.svg` which works well, but is terribly slow.

Searching the Web and SO only gets me libraries to do this inside some programming language (php, js, C#, ...). I could write myself a small program to do this, but I would prefer an existing tool (other than inkscape as it is quite slow).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible using `librsvg2`

All the details are [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=820965)

Comment: Hi ThibThib, `librsvg2` looks great and is fast. But is cuts parts from the image off. Any clue how I can simulate the `--export-area-drawing` feature of inkscape?

Comment: Works now, I simply had to recompute the actual size of the svgs (which was wrong) by a script (which is possible as the images have a fairly simple structure). Thanks again :)

Comment: Eg benchmark: svg to png conversion with a large file I have took 1m18s in Inkscape and 3.5s with librsvg2.

Answer (score 0):

The [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) library also has command-line tools that can do this. While it certainly supports SVG I'm not sure if it will give the same quality of results as InkScape unless your svg's are fairly simple..

Answer (score 0):

I you want to batch export whole or parts of SVG files to PNG in different sizes take a look at my tool [inkmake](https://github.com/wader/inkmake).